# Add additional templates to the templates drop down on add page menu

Tags: page-template

I'd like to add a custom page template to the drop down menu shown in the picture.

[image]

Had a good google at this but couldn't find anything, was too hard to form a concise query.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to add this template via a plugin or using the theme? If you want to use the theme you need several things:

1. The PHP file which will be responsible for the page. The file itself can be named in two ways: `page-{slug}.php` or `page-{id}.php`. [Here is an explanation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/#page-templates-within-the-template-hierarchy) what each one of them does.
2. You need to add the template name. Right after the opening `<?php` tag you need to add:

   /* Template Name: Your Template Name */

This name will be also used in the drop down.
 3. You need to code the logic for the template.

[Here is a good article](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) on page templates.